# react-native cant achieve borderRadius result as I want

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

Hi guys so i try to add two icons of hearts like in this picture:
[image]

I tried to make these components:

```
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <View style={styles.xButton} />
        <View style={styles.heartButton} />
      </View>
```

my styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  heartButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#FB4C61',
    height: 80,
    width: 60,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 100,
    // borderRadius: 10,
    // borderWidth: 1,
    // borderColor: '#fff',
  },
  xButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#182343',
    height: 80,
    width: 60,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderTopRightRadius: 100,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 100,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    zIndex: 999,
    alignItems: 'center',
    top: 200,
  },
```

The result i get in my phone:
[image]

I am using figma for design, maybe I should export all item and add it like image?

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest you, to use images instead of creating borders for this type of curves design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view with a certain borderRadius and transform it over an angle like below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  my_component: {
    width: 110,
    height: 110,
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopStartRadius: 45,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    top: '40%',
    transform: [{rotate: '135deg'}],
  },
  leftComponent: {
    transform: [{rotate: '135deg'}],
    left: -55,
  },
  rightComponent: {
    transform: [{rotate: '315deg'}],
    right: -55,
  },
});

class Page extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}>
        <View style={[styles.my_component, styles.leftComponent]} />
        <View style={[styles.my_component, styles.rightComponent]} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Page;
```

The position is set to **absolute**. The result achieved looks like: [screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVqlj.jpg)

I haven't added any Icons, but icons must also be positioned using **position: 'absolute'** and move them accordingly.

I believe the result is the closest to what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would give you your shape ([expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@romchambe/rounded-flag))

in render :

```
  <View style={styles.topFlag} />
  <View style={styles.centerFlag} />
  <View style={styles.bottomFlag} />
```

in styles

```
  centerFlag: {
    height: 20, 
    width: 60, 
    backgroundColor: "green",
    borderLeftColor: "green", 
    borderTopRightRadius: 9,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
  },
  bottomFlag: {
    height: 30, 
    width: 0, 
    borderBottomColor: "transparent",
    borderLeftColor: "green", 
    borderLeftWidth: 52,
    borderBottomWidth: 30,
  },
  topFlag: {
    height: 30, 
    width: 0, 
    borderTopColor: "transparent",
    borderLeftWidth: 52,
    borderLeftColor: "green", 
    borderTopWidth: 30,
  }
```

you can get inspiration in [this tuto](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native)